# округление до сотых

Tags: javascript

В общем есть ф-я для округления до сотых

js

```
var rounded = function(number){
    return Math.round(parseFloat(number) * 100) / 100;
}
```

Работает на ура с одинокими значениями, но у меня есть множество операций сложения и вычитания `n` количества значений, и бывает проскакивают значения типа 892.299999999 и тд. Вопрос в том , есть ли более универсальный вариант для округления

Comment: это на самом деле не округление, а урезание.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Может так: https://jsfiddle.net/IonDen/eqj36j1w/

```
var rounded = function(number){
    return +number.toFixed(2);
}

console.log(rounded(29.49999)); //29.5
console.log(rounded(15.75621900432)); //15.76
```

Comment: попробуйте 3186,4 отнять 987.12 и отнять 654.65, у меня выходит 1544.62(9)^в периоде

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/IonDen/kxbLqnt1/